# SSRS Execution log - activity tracking at folder level

Tags: reporting-services

I have recently launch ssrs 2016 for internal customers. I am trying to track user activities and have few questions based on analysis I have done so far. any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

1.) SSRS only stores 60 days of execution log by default and will internally delete any old entries. can we increase this period?

2.) Does SSRS execution log track activities at folder level as I see few users have visited report server/ report manager but can’t track their activities at all probably because they have not clicked on any reports or apps yet?

3.) I have uploaded few excel tool kits in one of the folders, are non-ssrs reports traceable using execution log?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can increase the execution log period. I typically use 400 days as that gives me a year to check if a report is no longer required etc. To change the setting, connect to the server using SSMS, right-click the server and go to properties. Then click the advanced page/tb on the left and changethe `ExecutionLogDaysKept` value.
2. The execution log records **execution** of reports, **not** navigation of folders etc. It records parameter values etc but also does **not** record subreports if they are called from a parent report.
3. I don't know if these are logged, why not simply open one and check the logs?

Comment: 1.) I use SSMS 2014 and it does have any advanced setting like you mentioned.     
2.) Make sense. thank you                                                                                      3.) I tried few things but don't see anything on those uploads. I see them in Catalog table but not in execution log at all.

Comment: You need to connect to reporting services from SSMS not the database engine. The advanced settings ARE there.